# Route:list laravel 5 not changed

Tags: laravel-5, routes

It's my first time deploying laravel on shared host.

I have a problem when adding some function on controller that already listed on routes.php.
Everything is ok when I run it on local, but when it's on shared host, and I run `php artisan route:list` the list doesn't updated

Here's my controller :

```
public function getIndex(){
    return view('content.login');
}

public function postIsLogin(Request $data){
    ...
}

public function getLogout(){
    ...
}
```

And this is my routes.php

```
Route::controller('/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('/driver','DriverController');
Route::controller('/pushnotif','PushNotificationController');
Route::controller('/','DashboardController');
```

I add getLogout() function, but when I run `php artisan route:list` there's no route for getLogout() function.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What if you remove "/" ?

Comment: @Nvan I've try to change anything on routes.php, but any changes on routes.php don't effect on `php artisan route:list`

Comment: what if you add this route ? Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@getIndex');

Comment: @Nvan I've done that too, still `php artisan route:list` not updating. the route list still the same as old one. thank you very fast respond

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usually caused by route cache, try to run `php artisan route:clear`